# solr on tomcat always trying to create default collection1

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr, lucene

I have installed the tomcat 7 and solr 4.7 with following configuration:

Server configuration: **/opt/tom-solr/conf/server.xml**

```
<Service name="solr">
    <Connector port="8082" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="solr-live" defaultHost="solr-live">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
        </Realm>
        <Host name="solr-live"  appBase="/opt/tom-solr/webapps/solr/"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="access-" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="common" />
            <Context path="" docBase="/opt/tom-solr/webapps/solr/solr.war" crossContext="true">
                <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/home/--------------/cwasolr/app" override="true"/>
            </Context>
            <Context path="/manager" docBase="/opt/tom-solr/webapps/manager"
                     antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" />

        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

I have added the solr.war file in : **/opt/tom-solr/webapps/solr/solr.war**

In App folder: **/home/rishi/--------/cwasolr/app**

Has following files:

```
4 drwxrwxr-x 4 rishi rishi 4096 May 12 20:22 celebrity
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 rishi rishi 1715 Feb 18 16:18 solr.xml

./celebrity:
total 8
4 drwxrwxr-x 3 rishi rishi 4096 May 11 00:46 conf
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 rishi rishi   16 May  9 23:55 core.properties

./celebrity/conf:
total 28
 8 -rwxrwxrwx 1 rishi rishi  5788 May 10 23:57 schema.xml
12 -rw-r--r-- 1 rishi rishi 10853 May  6 15:24 solrconfig.xml
 4 -rwxrwxrwx 1 rishi rishi   347 Apr 26 18:35 stopwords.txt
 4 -rwxrwxrwx 1 rishi rishi  1213 Apr 26 18:35 synonyms.txt
```

File: ------/cwasolr/app/solr.xml

```
  <solrcloud>
    <str name="host">${host:}</str>
    <int name="hostPort">${jetty.port:8983}</int>
    <str name="hostContext">${hostContext:solr}</str>
    <int name="zkClientTimeout">${zkClientTimeout:30000}</int>
    <bool name="genericCoreNodeNames">${genericCoreNodeNames:true}</bool>
  </solrcloud>

  <shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory"
    class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
    <int name="socketTimeout">${socketTimeout:0}</int>
    <int name="connTimeout">${connTimeout:0}</int>
  </shardHandlerFactory>

</solr>
```

But when I am starting the tomcat from any location, it start searching to default collection1 from that location. I have already created a core name celebrity and its working fine. But getting error for collection1.

Suppose I am at **/home/rishi/projects/** and starting the tomcat, then getting following errors in error logs:

```
5/12/2014 8:29:36 PM ERROR CoreContainer Failed to load file /home/rishi/projects/solr/collection1/solrconfig.xml
5/12/2014 8:29:36 PM ERROR CoreContainer Unable to create core: collection1
5/12/2014 8:29:36 PM ERROR CoreContainer null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core: collection1 



org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config file /home/rishi/projects/solr/collection1/solrconfig.xml
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:530)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:597)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:258)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/home/rishi/projects/solr/collection1/conf'
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:342)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:288)
    at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:116)
    at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:86)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:140)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:527)
    ... 9 more
```